# Are there any subtle differences in the greetings, "Ave" and "Salve"?

Tags: vocabulary, word-comparison

When greeting someone, are there any subtle differences between "Ave" and "Salve"? Can both be used to greet and respond? E.g.

> Marcus: Ave, Cicero.
>
> Cicero: Salve, Marce.

Or, vice versa:

> Vergilius: Salve, Ovidi.
>
> Ovidius: Ave, Vergili.

Furthermore, is one in a higher register than the other? Would one be used more often by plebeians? Or by aristocrats?

Comment: My first thought is that if I ever meet a _verum corpus_ or a _Maria,_ I'll say _ave,_ otherwise _salve._ ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what I got:

Both are translated as a salutation -at times with a reference to God-, and are quite interchangeable, but they have different origins.

- **Ave** comes from the imperative form of [aveo](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Daveo2), which means *to be/fare well*.
- **Salve** comes from the imperative form of [salveo](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dsalveo), *to be well/in good health*. Note that this health can be physical or spiritual -salvation-, (hence *God save you*.)

So both are basically *be well*, but an emphasis -if any- might be implied in **performance (ave)** or **health (salve)**.

I think the etymology means the distinction should have been valid, at least at the beginning. In contrast, *ave* has also been translated as *God save you*, e.g. at least in translations of the Hail Mary (or Lc 1, 28) to Spanish, [Aragonese](https://an.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ave_Mar%C3%ADa), [Catalan](https://ca.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avemaria) and [Sardinian](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deus_ti_salvet_Maria) (the Greek version uses χαῖρε as salutation, which means rejoice).

Answer (score 2):

Salve is, from what I've observed, the commoner greeting. It certainly is the one used more in Latin instruction.

Comment: Salve! And welcome to the site! My experience coincides with yours: *salve* seems to be much more common as a greeting in modern spoken Latin than *ave*. Do you know if there's a difference in meaning or nuance, or does *salve* just happen to be the more common one?

Comment: I'm not sure @JoonasIlmavirta