# "Ave Maria" versus "Dios te salve María"

Tags: christianity, spanish

The ancient Christian prayer *Ave Maria* derives mostly from texts found in the Gospel of Luke. In particular, in Luke 1:28 ([Vulgata](https://www.sacred-texts.com/bib/vul/luk001.htm#028)), we find:

> Et ingressus angelus ad eam dixit: Ave gratia plena: Dominus tecum: benedicta tu in mulieribus.

Let us focus on the first part of the salute, *Ave gratia plena*. The [original (?) Greek](https://biblehub.com/text/luke/1-28.htm) uses the words *Χαῖρε, κεχαριτωμένη* which seem to mean "Greetings, [you] favored with grace". This is consistent with the Latin, as well as with the English version of the *Ave Maria* (the latter being "Hail Mary, full of grace").

However, when it comes to Spanish, things look different. The greeting is instead "Dios te salve María, llena eres de gracia". So, instead of using an equivalent to *ave* or "hail", it uses "Dios te salve", which translates as *Salvet te Deus*, or "May God save you". This looks so different from the "original Greek/Latin". Moreover, the "[official](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ESL0506/__PVJ.HTM)" (Vatican) Spanish translation of the Gospel of Luke for such verse doesn't greatly differ from the Greek/Latin and English versions:

> El Angel entró en su casa y la saludó, diciendo: «¡Alégrate!, llena de gracia, el Señor está contigo».

*Alégrate* means "rejoice". In any case, it doesn't have anything like "may God save you".

What can explain the difference between the Spanish translation and the Greek/Latin versions?

PS: It might be interesting to notice that the [Portuguese](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ave_Maria) and [Italian](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ave_Maria) versions use *ave*, whereas the [French](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Je_vous_salue_Marie) uses an entirely different formula to all of the above, namely "Je vous salue Marie" (I salute you, Mary). It would be interesting to compare with more languages, but my knowledge stops there.

Comment: If it's of any use, the formula _"Dios te salve"_ was already used as a translation for Latin _"salve"_ [in a Cathecism book written circa 1400](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=0&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=030919\016\C000O03092019163617681.1016.1012&desc={B}+{I}+dios+te+salve{|I},+en+todos+los+medios,+en+{I}CORDE+{|I}+{|B}{BR}&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto0).

Comment: Also used in a [retelling of the Biblical passage in 1305](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=4&ordenar1=3&ordenar2=0&FID=030919\016\C003O03092019164640412.1016.1012&desc={B}+{I}+Dios+te+salve{|I},+en+{I}0-1401{|I},+en+todos+los+medios,+en+{I}CORDE+{|I}+{|B}{BR}&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto4): _"El angel entro, o ella era, e saludola e dixo: Dios te salve, plena de gracia. El seynor es con tu [...]"_

Comment: Looks like it was first used [around ~1240](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=Dios+te+salve&autor=&titulo=&ano1=&ano2=1401&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000).

Comment: @walen Thanks! Looks interesting. Btw, last link is not working.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I forgot to mention that in the third link you have to click `[Recuperar]` in order to show the search results (can't link them directly).

Comment: @walen You have the makings of a good answer there! Want to put it together and get some rep? (If not, I'll compile it all later.)

Comment: @Draconis As I said to luchonacho in chat... I don't want to post an answer because, as much as I like Latin, I'm not really an expert nor a user of the stack, and I'd rather have some veteran user post a complete answer with proper references.

Comment: @Draconis Also, my theory about _Ave_ → _Salve_ → _Dios te salve_ is missing the key part: why Vulgata's _Ave_ turned into _Salve_. My bet is some later translation from original Greek where the translator realized that, given the context of greeting a soon-to-be-pregnant woman, translating χαῖρε as _Salve_ instead of _Ave_ [would make more sense](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/4367); however, since I don't know of any such translation using _Salve Maria gratia plena_, that remains pure speculation.